# Vue: How to force www

Tags: .htaccess, vue.js, vue-router, vue-cli

**Hello**,
I have a website in **Vue Cli 4**. Is there a way to always have www like this on the web? Just redirect **non-www** to **www**

I have:

```
https://website.cz
```

I want:

```
https://www.website.cz
```

can this be done purely via VUE or is there no other option than htaccess? Or how to configure htaccess to work in development mode (npm serve) too?

Answer (score 1):

`.htaccess` try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^website.cz [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.website.cz/$1 [L,R=301]
```

see [redirect https - www](https://htaccessbook.com/htaccess-redirect-https-www/)

Comment: Use http**s** for the rewite rule

Comment: yeah, so i can't just with VUE without using htaccess, right?